# Check valid string encoding with PHP's intl (ICU) features

Tags: php, unicode, icu

Using the features currently available in PHP's **intl** wrapper for ICU, how would you go about checking for validity of a string's encoding? (e.g. check for valid UTF-8)

I know it can be done with mbstring, iconv() and PCRE but I'm specifically interested in intl with this question.

Comment: You could just convert it to UCS4 and back and see if you get an error. If you have valid UTF8, this is a completely reversible procedure. This probably isn't the *fastest* solution, but unless you're checking megabytes of data, you should be fine.

Comment: I expect that would work. But which part of intl does it? http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging and found [ICU unorm2_normalize() documentation](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/unorm2_8h.html#a0a596802db767da410b4b04cb75cbc53). Its pErrorCode out parameter is interesting. The standard ICU error codes start around line 620 of [utypes.h](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/utypes_8h_source.html). So I tried this test script:

```
$s = 'tête-à-tête';
echo "normalizer_normalize(\$s) >> " 
     . var_export(normalizer_normalize($s), 1) . "\n";
$s = "\xFF" . $s;
echo "normalizer_normalize(\$s) >> " 
     . var_export($r=normalizer_normalize($s), 1) . "\n";
if ($r===false)
    echo "normalizer_normalize() error: " 
         . intl_get_error_message() . "\n";
// which outputs:
normalizer_normalize($s) >> 'tête-à-tête'
normalizer_normalize($s) >> false
normalizer_normalize() error: Error converting input string to UTF-16: U_INVALID_CHAR_FOUND
```

So I guess a test based on that and looking for the following three error codes would be a decent indication of bad UTF-8 encoding:

> U_INVALID_CHAR_FOUND   Character conversion: Unmappable input sequence.
>   U_TRUNCATED_CHAR_FOUND     Character conversion: Incomplete input sequence.
>   U_ILLEGAL_CHAR_FOUND   Character conversion: Illegal input sequence/combination of input units.

Or when I'm feeling lazy I could just use

```
normalizer_normalize($s)===false
```

Btw: I'm confused by this line of the ICU API spec:

> **pErrorCode**    Standard ICU error code.
>   Its input value must pass the
>   **U_SUCCESS**() test, or else the function
>   returns immediately. Check for
>   **U_FAILURE**() on output or use with
>   function chaining. (See User Guide for
>   details.)

The "the function returns immediately" phrase is encouraging re performance of my test but does "the function" refer to unorm2_normalize() or U_SUCCESS()? Any ideas?

Comment: See http://userguide.icu-project.org/design#TOC-Error-Handling - basically, if the error code was already a failure coming in, functions will just return and not try to do any (more) work.   PHP's wrappers ought to be resetting the error value everytime they call the ICU functions.   Here, "the function" refers to normalize(), not to U_SUCCESS().

Answer (score 2):

UConverter can be used Since PHP 5.5. The manual doesn't exist. See https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uconverter for API.

```
function replace_invalid_byte_sequence($str)
{
    return UConverter::transcode($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
}

function replace_invalid_byte_sequence2($str)
{
    return (new UConverter('UTF-8', 'UTF-8'))->convert($str);
}

function utf8_check_encoding($str)
{
    return $str === UConverter::transcode($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
}

function utf8_check_encoding2($str)
{
    return $str === (new UConverter('UTF-8', 'UTF-8'))->convert($str);
}

// Table 3-8. Use of U+FFFD in UTF-8 Conversion
// http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.1.0/ch03.pdf)
$str =  "\x61"."\xF1\x80\x80"."\xE1\x80"."\xC2"."\x62"."\x80"."\x63"
    ."\x80"."\xBF"."\x64";
$expected = 'a���b�c��d';

var_dump([
    $expected === replace_invalid_byte_sequence($str),
    $expected === replace_invalid_byte_sequence2($str)
],[
    false === utf8_check_encoding($str),
    false === utf8_check_encoding2($str)
]);
```